# Ajax post success function not executing after response from express to set cookie

Tags: ajax, express, post, firebase-authentication, setcookie

I'm attempting to store a session cookie after a successful firebase-authentication login. All the firebase functions appear to be executing correctly. I'm able to retrieve my idToken after logging. The Post correctly sends this idToken to the server where it is validated. However, I'm getting stuck on the last step which is to store the session cookie in my success function, which doesn't execute.

To troubleshoot this I go to the Chrome Dev Tools and access the network tab and turn on preserve log. Here I can see my post request. When I click on response it says "Failed to load response data". This at least tells me that the post is partially working. The client is at a minimum sending the idToken, but I can't verify that the response is being sent from the server. Additionally, when I navigate to the Application tab of the chrome dev tools and click refresh I don't see my session cookie there.

Here is the client side code:

```
btnLogin.addEventListener('click', e => {
    // Get eamil and pass
    // TODO: Check for real email
    const email = txtEmail.value;
    const pass = txtPassword.value;

    // As httpOnly cookies are to be used, do not persist any state client side.
    firebase.auth().setPersistence(firebase.auth.Auth.Persistence.NONE);

    // Sign in
    firebase.auth().signInWithEmailAndPassword(email,pass).then((userCredential) => {
        // Get the user's ID token as it is needed to exchange for a session cookie.
        userCredential.user.getIdToken().then((idToken) => {
            // Session login endpoint is queried and the session cookie is set.
            // TODO: Add CSRF protection);
            $.ajax({
                type: 'post',
                //accepts: 'json',
                data: {idToken: idToken},
                //dataType: 'json',
                contentType: 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded',
                success: function(data) {
                    console.log('MADE IT TO THE SUCCESS FUNCTION');
                    //document.cookie = data;
                    firebase.auth().signOut();
                    $('#loginForm').before(' \
                        <div class="alert alert-secondary" role="alert"> \
                            The login was succesful! \
                        </div> \
                    ');
                    //setTimeout(window.location.assign('/admin-manage'), 5000);
                },
                error: function() {
                    console.log('post error');
                    $('#loginForm').before(' \
                        <div class="alert alert-danager" role="alert"> \
                            The idToken post failed! \
                        </div> \
                    ');
                },
                timeout: 5000
            });
        });
    });
});
```

Here is the server side code:

```
/* POST FOR SESSION INITIALIZATION */
app.post('/admin-login', (req, res) => {
    // Get the ID token passed and the CSRF token.
    var idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
    // TODO: CSRF TOKEN
    // Set session expiration to 2 days.
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 * 1000;
    // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
    // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
    // We could also choose to enforce that the ID token auth_time is recent.
    adminApp.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedIdToken) => {
        console.log('ID TOKEN: ' + idToken);
        // Only process if the user just signed in the last 5 minutes
        if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedIdToken.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
            // Create session cookie and store it serverside
            return adminApp.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn});
        }
        else {
            throw new error('The IDToken has expired');
        }
    })
    // eslint-disable-next-line promise/always-return
    .then((sessionCookie) => {
        console.log(sessionCookie);
        //Set session cookie on client side
        const options = {maxAge: expiresIn, httpOnly: false, secure: false};
        res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
        res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
    })
    .catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).send();
    });
});
```

**EDIT**
Here is an image of the network view from me running chrom dev tools.
[CHROME DEV TOOLS APPLICATION VIEW](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wxrXd.png)
As you can see the post script gets canceled.

Here is a detailed view of the request headers:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Sp345.png)

**EDIT #2**
I've made so more changes to the server-side code and still haven't seen any change in results. Here is the new server-side code:

```
/* POST FOR SESSION INITIALIZATION */
app.post('/admin-login', (req, res, next) => {
    // Get the ID token passed and the CSRF token.
    var idToken = req.body.idToken.toString();
    // TODO: CSRF TOKEN
    // Set session expiration to 2 days.
    const expiresIn = 60 * 60 * 24 * 2 * 1000;
    // Create the session cookie. This will also verify the ID token in the process.
    // The session cookie will have the same claims as the ID token.
    // We could also choose to enforce that the ID token auth_time is recent.
    adminApp.auth().verifyIdToken(idToken).then((decodedClaims) => {
        console.log('DECODED CLAIMS AUD: ' + decodedClaims.uid );
        // Only process if the user just signed in the last 5 minutes
        if (new Date().getTime() / 1000 - decodedClaims.auth_time < 5 * 60) {
            // Create session cookie and store it serverside
            // eslint-disable-next-line promise/no-nesting
            adminApp.auth().createSessionCookie(idToken, {expiresIn}).then((sessionCookie) => {
                console.log(sessionCookie);
                //Set session cookie on client side
                const options = {
                    maxAge: expiresIn,
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: false
                };
                res.set('Content-Type', 'application/json');
                res.cookie('session', sessionCookie, options);
                res.end(JSON.stringify({status: 'success'}));
            });
        }
        else {
            throw new error('The IDToken has expired');
        }
    }).catch((error) => {
        console.log(error);
        res.status(401).send('UNAUTHROIZED REQUEST!');
    });
});
```

I also took a wireshark capture on my loopback adapter so that I could capture the localhost traffic. I can see the HTTP response with the set-cookie tag, but not sure what the problem is. See the image below:
[HTTP Post Response Wireshark Capture](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LdL98.png)

**EDIT #3**
I've finally made a little progress. I noticed the URI in my wireshark capture wasn't "samesite" so I added the "sameSite: 'None'" option to my set-cookie options.

So my new options are:

```
const options = {
                    maxAge: expiresIn,
                    httpOnly: true,
                    secure: false,
                    sameSite: 'None'
                };
```

This fixed the issue on my localhost development environment. However, I changed the secure option to true then did a firebase deploy. After the deployment I logged into the production environment and found that the cookie would not generate. So the only question left is why it won't work in the production environment.

**EDIT #4**
Alright, I'm losing my mind. I changed the options back to how I had them in EDIT #3 so that I could continue working the app, and the session cookie is no longer being set again. I'm at a complete loss as to why it won't work now. I even went into chrome to clear all browsing history in hopes this would resolve the issue, but no luck. If anyone can shed light on what is happening here I would greatly appreciate it.

Comment: Which log messages do you see on the server?  Do you know exactly which code path the server code is taking?  And, are you saying that neither the success or error ajax callbacks are being called on the client?  In other words, no response from the POST is received on the client?

Comment: FYI, `document.cookie = data;` would not be a valid cookie if that's what you were trying to do.  `data` in this case would probably be `{"status": "success"}`. and that's not a valid cookie format.  `document.cookie` will already contain the cookie that your server set.

Comment: I see a potential issue here.  The expiration argument for `res.cookie()` is the actual date/time of the expiration, not how many milliseconds from now that it expires.  So, you are setting an expiration date that is BEFORE now so the cookie will immediately expire.

Comment: The documentation says the maxAge variable is miliseconds, not an actual date/time value. I think you're confusing it with the "expires" parameter. Also, the session cookie string value should be fine the way it is. I thought res.cookie method handled the JSON stringify between the cookie name and string value. Thanks for help